# Kafka consumer "Failed to add leader for partitions" error running on Mesos

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper, mesos

I am running a Kafka cluster of 6 brokers using the [mesos/kafka](https://github.com/mesos/kafka) library. I am able to add and start the brokers over 6 different machines and to post messages into the cluster using the Python SimpleProducer and the kafka-console-producer.sh script.

However I am not able to get the consumers working properly. I am running the following consumer command:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --zookeeper 192.168.1.199:2181 --topic test --from-beginning --consumer.config config/consumer.properties --delete-consumer-offsets
```

In the consumer.properties file I set the group.id to `my.group` and set the `zookeeeper.connect` to a number of nodes in the zookeeper ensemble. I get the following warninng messages from running this consumer:

```
            [2015-09-24 16:01:06,609] WARN [my.group_my_host-1443106865779-b5a3a1e1-leader-finder-thread], Failed to add l
    eader for partitions [test,4],[test,1],[test,5],[test,2],[test,0],[test,3]; will retry (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherM
    anager$LeaderFinderThread)
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:127)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset(SimpleConsumer.scala:166)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.handleOffsetOutOfRange(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:60)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:177)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.addPartitions(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:87)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager.addFetcherForPartitions(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:95)
            at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
    {'some':2}
    [2015-09-24 16:20:02,362] WARN [my.group_my_host-1443108001180-fa0c93e4-leader-finder-thread], Failed to add leader for partitions [test,4],[test,1],[test,5],[test,2],[test,0],[test,3]; will retry (kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread)
    java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException
            at kafka.network.BlockingChannel.send(BlockingChannel.scala:100)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.liftedTree1$1(SimpleConsumer.scala:78)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.kafka$consumer$SimpleConsumer$$sendRequest(SimpleConsumer.scala:68)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.getOffsetsBefore(SimpleConsumer.scala:127)
            at kafka.consumer.SimpleConsumer.earliestOrLatestOffset(SimpleConsumer.scala:166)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherThread.handleOffsetOutOfRange(ConsumerFetcherThread.scala:60)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:177)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread$$anonfun$addPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map1.foreach(Map.scala:109)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.addPartitions(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:172)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:87)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager$$anonfun$addFetcherForPartitions$2.apply(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:772)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashMap1.foreach(HashMap.scala:224)
            at scala.collection.immutable.HashMap$HashTrieMap.foreach(HashMap.scala:403)
            at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:771)
            at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherManager.addFetcherForPartitions(AbstractFetcherManager.scala:77)
            at kafka.consumer.ConsumerFetcherManager$LeaderFinderThread.doWork(ConsumerFetcherManager.scala:95)
            at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:60)
    ...
    // Lots more of this
    ...
    Consumed 1 messages
```

I'm not sure why it is unable to add a leader, the leaders seem to be in Zookeeper already. As well as all these error messages I can only ever get one message through to the consumer. The string `{'some':2}` is a message I sent from the console producer.

I found this error in the `server.log` of one of the Mesos slaves, not sure if it is relevant:

```
[2015-09-24 17:09:41,926] ERROR Closing socket for /192.168.1.199 because of error (kafka.network.Processor)
java.io.IOException: Broken pipe
            at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.write0(Native Method)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.write(SocketDispatcher.java:47)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.writeFromNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:93)
            at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.write(IOUtil.java:65)
            at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.write(SocketChannelImpl.java:471)
            at kafka.api.TopicDataSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:123)
            at kafka.network.MultiSend.writeTo(Transmission.scala:101)
            at kafka.api.FetchResponseSend.writeTo(FetchResponse.scala:231)
            at kafka.network.Processor.write(SocketServer.scala:472)
            at kafka.network.Processor.run(SocketServer.scala:342)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Any suggestions as to what might be happening with the consumer or where I might look to troubleshoot the problem?**

Zookeeper broker partition state for one of the log partitions:

```
[zk: localhost:2181(CONNECTED) 166] get /brokers/topics/test/partitions/0/state
{"controller_epoch":1,"leader":0,"version":1,"leader_epoch":0,"isr":[0]}
```

OS: Ubuntu 14.0.4
Mesos: 0.23
Kafka: 2.10-0.8.2.1

**Update:** doing some further testing using the `kafka-console-consumer.sh` the messages do seem to be getting through. The error messages are constant so you do not see all the messages in `stdout`. **The Python `KafkaConsumer` fails immediately** with a `FailedPayloadsError`.

Answer (score 5):

I think you need look into value of property "**advertised.host.name**". I have also recently faced this issue and fixed using above property. 
Please make sure that you have mentioned correct **IP** address for each **BROKER**. 
Let me know if doesn't works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Bector. The mesos/kafka scheduler does not appear to let me set this value. I have put in a server.properties file whilst adding a broker but it does not appear to actually get set. Even setting the port with that library does not work for me. I will raise an issue on their Github page.

Comment: It might be not allowing you to modify it but the property which you are setting from server.properties it is getting override from some where that's why you are not able to see the modified changes. Its good you have raised this issue but you should be able to modify this property.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper your.zookeeper:2181 --describe --topic your_topic
```

This will show which broker is the leader of each of your topic's partitions (see this link for more details: http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#quickstart_multibroker)

In my case, one of the brokers that was set as a leader had failed and no longer existed. A new leader should have been assigned but for some reason it wasn't.

I fixed the issue by:

1. Stopping all producers and consumers
2. Restarting each remaining broker

I then re-ran the `describe` command (from above) and could see that the failed broker was no longer listed as a leader.

I then brought up a new broker with the same id as the failed broker.  Kafka took it from there and brought over all of the data from my other brokers (this requires that your topic has an adequate replication factor). Once the data was over, Kafka made the broker the partition leader.

Lastly, I re-started the producers and consumers.

Comment: I face this issue currently and when i try your command  i get   Topic:MY_TOPIC PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: MY_TOPIC Partition: 0 Leader: -1 Replicas: 1012 Isr:

Comment: @Ratha Did you find a fix to it? I have the same issue.

Comment: @user2441441 no i couldn't, but I upgraded to kafka 0.10.0.1, and using high level consumer/producer APIs..Now things are working fine

Answer (score 0):

My issue was:

1. Run zookeeper
2. Created topic
3. Run kafka

Then I get "No leader found exception"

But when I created a topic when Zookeeper and Kafka were running normally it worked ok.